# Unable to output the costmap_2d occupancy grid array

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's how my code looks -

```
costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS *global_costmap = new costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS("global_costmap", buffer);
```

I have specified the following params in my configuration file -

```
global_frame: odom
rolling_window: true
track_unknown_space: true

plugins:
  - {name: obstacles_laser,           type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
  - {name: inflation,                 type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

I am able to publish the occupancy grid using the terminal by running rostopic echo -n1 /global_costmap/costmap.

However, when I add the following line to my code -

```
unsigned char* global_og = global_costmap->getCostmap()->getCharMap() ; 

cout << global_og[10] << endl;
```

I see some strange characters being published.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375855/unable-to-output-the-costmap_2d-occupancy-grid-array/) by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 310 on 2021-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it shows the cost of the occupancy grid as a letter, not a number. I think you can solve this problem by casting it as a number.

example

```
unsigned char* global_og = global_costmap->getCostmap()->getCharMap() ;

cout << (int)global_og[10] << endl; // cast to int
```

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-04-15**:
Thank you!